# Asynchronous Callbacks impossible nesting

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

When I define my routes in node.js, I am trying to call some middleware to load the users depending on the request.  However, the asynchronous nature of pulling the users from the database seem to make it impossible.

**Middleware that uses another function to connect to database**

```
function loadUsers (req, res, next) {
  userings.openPlayers(function(ps) {
    req.user = ps[req.params.id - 1];
  });
  console.log(req.user);
}
```

**Route that uses middleware**

```
app.get('/player/game/:id', loadUsers, function(res, req) {
  console.log(req.user);
});
```

**Function that connects to db and returns users in callback**

```
function openPlayers(callback) {
  db.hgetall("players", function(err, objs) {
    var players = [];
    // Objects of Response
    for (var k in objs) {
      // Items are the individual key-value object
      var newPlayer = {};
      var items = JSON.parse(objs[k]);
      for (var x in items) {
        // x is the key for each object
        newPlayer[x] = items[x];
      }
      players.push(newPlayer);
    }
    callback(players);
  });
}
module.exports.openPlayers = openPlayers;
```

The database connection function works great!  My specific problem is how to use the callback to return the users to the `loadUsers` function so that my route can use it as middleware.
Thanks!

Comment: You want to invoke `next()` from the callback.

Comment: `req.user` still returns as `undefined` from the route though.

Comment: I have inspected an confirmed it is returning the expected value.  I'm baffled on this issue after a few hours of debugging.

Comment: I do not.  Should I add it before it?

Comment: @derek_duncan No. Sorry. You can ignore my previous comment about `app.use()`. I'd just misread part of the question.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Do you need any other information I can give?

Comment: Don't ignore the `err` param in the `hgetall` callback, and follow the node convention of `callback(err, players)` instead of `callback(players)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to call `next` in your middleware

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  userings.openPlayers(function(ps) {
    req.user = ps[req.params.id - 1];
    next();
  });

  // this is pointless here
  // console.log(req.user);
});
```

`req.user` is only set in the callback for the `openPlayers` function.

Comment: Right thank you for the answer, but it doesn't fix the problem like you said.  I'm trying to get `req.user` to return to the middleware without an endless chain of callbacks...

Comment: @derek_duncan: What do you mean by "endless chain of callbacks"?

Comment: I'm currently trying to not add another callback to fix this.  Any ideas on why `next()` is not returning the value?

Comment: @derek_duncan `next()` doesn't "return a value", it just calls the next callback function. It seems like you have an error somewhere else in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue may be in converting the `Object` [that `hsetall()` supplies](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#clienthgetallhash) to an `Array`.

The order that `for..in` iterates over keys of an `Object` isn't guaranteed (other than that it won't repeat), so the order of players/users may appear to change in `ps` from one conversion to the next.

It'd probably be better to keep the `Object`, using its keys as the `:id`, and just converting its values from JSON to `Object`s themselves:

```
for (var k in objs)
  objs[k] = JSON.parse(objs[k]);

callback(objs);
```

```
req.user = ps[req.params.id];
```

Comment: +1 for a much better method, but the issue is still not resolved.  The route cannot seem to return the user object from the callback even with `next()`

Comment: @derek_duncan Where are you expecting the result to appear? Based on the snippet, the user should be logged to STDOUT. But, if you're expecting it to appear in an HTTP client (browser), you'll need to use [`res.write()` and `res.end()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding). You can also use Express' [`res.send()` or `res.json()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send), which are shorthands for the other 2 methods.

Comment: This works if I call it within the `loadUsers` function.  Is there a way to call it from the `app.get` route instead like I originally was testing with `console.log`?

Comment: If you edit your answer with that last comment I'll mark as the answer.  It works, I just wish I could call it from the callback function in `loadUsers`